# J2ME: Crossplatform getting contacs with PIM

Tags: java-me, cross-platform, nokia, jsr75, pim

I have to develop solution based on getting data from address book.
Those data must be saved into text format. I coded it with Java™ Platform Micro Edition SDK 3.0.

`public void getAddrBook() throws Exception{
        addrStr= new StringBuffer("");
        pim = PIM.getInstance();
        try{
            contactList = (ContactList)pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
            itemList.removeAllElements();
            int kk=0;
            for (Enumeration items = contactList.items(); items.hasMoreElements();kk++) {
                PIMItem item = (PIMItem)items.nextElement();
                itemList.addElement(item);
                if (kk>5) break;
                //detailed enumeration of fields
                int[] fields = item.getPIMList().getSupportedFields();
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    int field = fields[i];
                    int dataType = item.getPIMList().getFieldDataType(field);
                    String label = item.getPIMList().getFieldLabel(field);
                    //checking type of PIMItem
                    //can be STRING, BOOLEAN, STRING_ARRAY, DATE, INT, BINARY
                    if (dataType==PIMItem.STRING){
                        for (int j=0; j

                    }
                    //String sValue = item.getString(field, 0);
                    //System.out.println("["+label+"] - "+sValue);
                    //System.out.println("["+label+"] - ");//+sValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PIMException e){
        throw new Exception("Some errors with access to address book");
        //TODO: check empty list and other

    }
}`

But this code works only in emulator and doesn't work in real phone. 
How should I use PIM for saving data in text format?

Also, I allowed access to contact book. I think error is using PIM structure.
I need some working sample. Who has it? (:

Comment: can you log exception somewhere in device and post it here..

Comment: yes, I can. It is "Invalid attribute argument: 0" message in exception.

Answer (score 2):

The JSR75 PIM API has security features built-in that require applications to be digitally signed by a trusted source. Signing can be done at sites like GeoTrust (I have used it for AT&T on a Sony Ericsson W810).

In addition to signing the application, you will need to enable permissions in the application's JAD file. The following 6 permissions are possible for the PIM API.

```
javax.microedition.pim.ContactList.read
javax.microedition.pim.ContactList.write
javax.microedition.pim.EventList.read
javax.microedition.pim.EventList.write
javax.microedition.pim.ToDoList.read
javax.microedition.pim.ToDoList.write
```